# installation with WAS Liberty server and DB2(How to give root access to user )

Tags: db2

I am trying to set up a standalone server setup with WAS Liberty server and DB2 database. I have installed IBM Installation Manager, WAS server and WAS supplementary and DB2.THe whole set up is done in ubuntu. I am new to DB2 Express c edition , so when i run the command for creating a database it is giving me a error saying as below. So i need to know the command for getting the root access to the user , seeing the number of the user and also need help in creating the document.[image]

Error message is SQL1092N  The requested command or operation failed because the user ID does 
not have the authority to perform the requested command or operation.  User 
ID: "****".

Comment: Please add the error message as text to your question (so it is searchable). Are you doing this as root or another user?